# Jdev 12c integrated weblogic server not starting-bea_wls_internal

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, soa

I am using Jdev 12c. Following error is coming in starting integrated weblogic server

following error occured:

```
<Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "bea_wls_internal".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

provide more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your server is not installed correctly.some files are missing.

try them again!

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/overview.html